# Spring Boot - Erro java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

estou com um erro no Spring e não estou conseguindo entender muito bem o que está acontecendo, poderiam me ajudar?

- LOG

```
09:25:43.038 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'listarVeiculosController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'veiculoRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'veiculoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.model.VeiculoCotacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.App.main(App.java:35)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'veiculoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.model.VeiculoCotacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.model.VeiculoCotacao
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

- listarVeiculosController

```
@Controller
public class ListarVeiculosController {

    @Autowired
    VeiculoRepository veiculoRepository;

    public void request(Exchange exchange) {
        try {
            RetornoData data = new RetornoData();
            List<BuscarVeiculosDTO> listaResponse = new ArrayList();
            List<VeiculoCotacao> listaVeiculos = new ArrayList();

            int anoModelo = Integer.parseInt(exchange.getProperty("year").toString());
            String stringPesquisa = exchange.getProperty("search_terms").toString();
            Boolean zeroKm = Boolean.parseBoolean(exchange.getProperty("zero_km").toString());

            //listaVeiculos = (List<VeiculoCotacao>) veiculoRepository.findBySearchTerms(anoModelo, stringPesquisa);
            listaVeiculos = (List<VeiculoCotacao>) veiculoRepository.findAll();

            for (VeiculoCotacao veiculoCotacao : listaVeiculos) {
                BuscarVeiculosDTO veiculo = new BuscarVeiculosDTO();

                veiculo.setCodigoMolicar(veiculoCotacao.getCdMolicar());
                veiculo.setMarca(veiculoCotacao.getMarca());
                veiculo.setModelo(veiculoCotacao.getModelo());

                listaResponse.add(veiculo);
            }

            data.setData(listaResponse);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(data);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            exchange.setException(new VeiculoException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

- VeiculoCotacao.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class VeiculoCotacao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private int idICarros;
    private int anoInicial;
    private int anoFinal;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private String cdMolicar;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getIdICarros() {
        return idICarros;
    }
    public void setIdICarros(int idICarros) {
        this.idICarros = idICarros;
    }
    public int getAnoInicial() {
        return anoInicial;
    }
    public void setAnoInicial(int anoInicial) {
        this.anoInicial = anoInicial;
    }
    public int getAnoFinal() {
        return anoFinal;
    }
    public void setAnoFinal(int anoFinal) {
        this.anoFinal = anoFinal;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
    public String getCdMolicar() {
        return cdMolicar;
    }
    public void setCdMolicar(String cdMolicar) {
        this.cdMolicar = cdMolicar;
    }



}
```

- VeiculoRepository.java

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.model.VeiculoCotacao;

@Repository
public interface VeiculoRepository extends CrudRepository<VeiculoCotacao, Integer>{


}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar também sua classe de configuração?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela sua stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.model.VeiculoCotacao
```

O que acontece é que sua classe `VeiculoCotacao` não está sendo reconhecida como uma entidade de persistência, provavelmente por falta de configuração.

Você pode indicar o pacote onde esta entidade se encontra através da seguinte anotação em sua aplicação/configuração:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"br.com.itau.ev9.fuse.model"})
```

É importante reforçar que caso você possua outros pacotes com entidades e não estejam abaixo da hierarquia da sua classe de aplicação, eles devem ser referenciados no array acima.

---

Incluindo também o link para a [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html) do `@EntityScan`:

> Configures the base packages used by auto-configuration when scanning
>   for entity classes.
>
> Using @EntityScan will cause auto-configuration to:
>
> ```
> Set the packages scanned for JPA entities.
> Set the packages used with Neo4J's SessionFactory.
> Set the initial entity set used with Spring Data MongoDB, Cassandra and Couchbase mapping contexts.
> ```
>
> One of basePackageClasses(), basePackages() or its alias value() may
>   be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages
>   are not defined scanning will occur from the package of the class with
>   this annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Em versões anterior a SpringBoot 3.x.x, você usaria o javax.persistence na classe Model, na versão SpringBoot 3.x.x, você deve usar jakarta.persistence.